# How to display a percentage with label in pie chart in windows phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
<charting:PieSeries 
          IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Count}">
    <charting:PieSeries.LegendItemStyle>
        <Style TargetType="charting:LegendItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4 0 5 4"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Maroon"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Silver"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </charting:PieSeries.LegendItemStyle>
</charting:PieSeries>
```

I want to display a name with percentage in pie chart. Above way its just generate a pie chart without label percentage